# Scrapy Custom Function Cannot Fire scrapy.Requests

Tags: scrapy

Seems the `yield scrapy.Requests` cannot be fired in a function like the following code.
Anyone could give me a help to clear me or help me fire?
Really appreciate for your help.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    ...

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url,
                             callback=self.parse_items)

    ...

    def parse_items(self, response):
        def __fire_here(response)

    ...

    def __fire_here(response):
        # Cannot fire here, why?
        yield scrapy.Request(url,
                             callback=self.parse_items)
```

Comment: Seems a silly questions. I want to do this, because I don't want to write duplicated code when processing some certain logic. Thank you for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid code duplication you can call your `__fire_here` function in this way:

```
def parse_items(self, response):
    yield self.__fire_here(response)

def __fire_here(self, response):
    # yield some request here
```

Your code seems to make endless calls from one function to another. Can you check your logics?

Comment: Great!! Thank you for your help. Use the "return" in __fire_here helps.
The scenario is: Our company is behind few proxy servers. When request gets 407 error, I need to switch the another proxy. If requests - 200, fire stop. If all proxy server tried, fire stop.